# Gauss seidel in VBA

Tags: vba, matrix

Trying to use Gauss seidel method to solve a 25 by 25 matrix to solve a 2D heat transfer chemical engineering problem.

But it doesnt go to 2nd iteration

```
Do While error > 0.1

temps0 = temps1(UBound(matrix1, 1), 1) ' Old temperature for error calculation

'Conducts the gauss algorithm for each row
For i = 1 To UBound(matrix1, 1)
    temps1(i, 1) = matrix1(i, UBound(matrix1, 2))
    For j = 1 To (UBound(matrix1, 2) - 1)
        If j <> i Then
            temps1(i, 1) = temps1(i, 1) - (matrix1(i, j) * temps1(j, 1))
        ElseIf j = i Then
            divider = matrix1(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
    temps1(i, 1) = temps1(i, 1) / divider
Next i

error = Abs((temps1(UBound(matrix1, 1), 1) - temps0) / temps1(UBound(matrix1,     1), 1))
iteration = iteration + 1

Loop
```

this is the do while loop for Gauss Seidel
Matrix1 is coeff matrix generated by previous functions

Really appreciate any help.
TY

Comment: When you say "it doesn't go to 2nd iteration", are you referring to the second iteration of the `i` loop, or the second iteration of the `j` loop?  And what does it do instead of going to the second iteration, i.e. does it crash, or does it just think that `matrix1` is only dimensioned `1 To 1, 1 To 2`, or something else?

Comment: what i meant is it does not update the temp1(1-D array).

Comment: single-step the code by using the F8 key, and see if the program flow is correct. .... if the loops take too many steps then insert breakpoints and use F5 to continue execution, which will stop at a breakpoint